# TypeScript: how to get function by name?

Tags: typescript

how to get a function by name, i'm tried this[funcName], but i'm get an error: "type has no index signature"?

Comment: Where are the functions defined? If they're named functions, your should be able to refer them directly by name.

Comment: Ok, my bad, i will try to clarify:  for example my goal is to do something like: $(domElement).bind(eventKey, this[funcName]); funcName - is an argument of otherMethod, so i need to dynamically attach eventHandlers

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. You might want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Right now we can only guess what kinds of things will fix your problem.  For example, you probably want `funcName` to be declared as type `keyof this` instead of `string`, so that `this[funcName]` resolves.  But for all I know this would lead to other problems.  So a complete and verifiable example would be best for everyone.

Comment: Are you going to pass parameters into these functions?

Answer (score -2):

```
this.functionName(arg1, arg2);
```

Replace *functionName* with the name of the function and enter replace arguments (if any or more) with *arg1, arg2*, if you have more just add more comma's.

Comment: But i want to do it dynamically, funcName - is a string argument of some other function.

Comment: Oh ok, sorry didn't get you. In that case you can use the javascript eval() function which turns a piece of string into code.

Comment: No, i don't need to invoke it, i just want to bind it as event handler. Such as:
$(domElement).bind(eventKey, this[funcName]);