# Get function descriptor by name:

Tags: typescript

How can I hook up an event to a function name which I have defined as a string? I'm tried this[funcName], but i'm get an error: "type has no index signature"?

What is should be instead this[someData[key]] to get a delegate of current class by name.

Test code sample:

```
<div data-eventclick='ClickHandler' />
...
public someFunction(domContex: HTMLElement) {
   let someData = domContext.dataset;
   someData.filter(key => string.prototype.startsWith("event"))
           .foreach(key => domContext.bind(key.substr(5), this[someData[key]]);
}

// It's can be as the result of this[someData[key]]
public ClickHandler() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is a duplicate question from the same person: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46694669/typescript-how-to-get-function-by-name

Answer (score 0):

You can add a index signature to your class:

```
class YourClass {
    [key: string]: Function;

    public someFunction(domContex: HTMLElement) {
        let someData = domContext.dataset;
        someData.filter(key => string.prototype.startsWith("event"))
            .foreach(key => domContext.bind(key.substr(5), this[someData[key]]);
    }
}
```

But this forces all your class members to be functions so you cannot have other properties.

---

Or if you just want to bypass the type checking you can just cast `this` to any and access the function. Note that you will lose any type checking once you cast to `any`:

```
(this as any)[someData[key]]()
```